# Cannot open File based on documentation example

Tags: rust

I can't seem to get the [example code from the `File` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) to work. I added the main function, etc:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

fn main(){
    let mut f = try!(File::create("foo.txt"));
    try!(f.write_all(b"Hello, world!"));

    let mut f = try!(File::open("foo.txt"));
    let mut s = String::new();
    try!(f.read_to_string(&mut s));
    assert_eq!(s, "Hello, world!");
}
```

Gives me these errors:

```
 file git:(master) ✗ rustc main.rs -o /tmp/rrust.out
<std macros>:5:8: 6:42 error: mismatched types:
 expected `()`,
    found `core::result::Result<_, _>`
(expected (),
    found enum `core::result::Result`) [E0308]
<std macros>:5 return $ crate:: result:: Result:: Err (
<std macros>:6 $ crate:: convert:: From:: from ( err ) ) } } )
main.rs:5:17: 5:46 note: in this expansion of try! (defined in <std macros>)
<std macros>:5:8: 6:42 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
<std macros>:5:8: 6:42 error: mismatched types:
 expected `()`,
    found `core::result::Result<_, _>`
(expected (),
    found enum `core::result::Result`) [E0308]
<std macros>:5 return $ crate:: result:: Result:: Err (
<std macros>:6 $ crate:: convert:: From:: from ( err ) ) } } )
main.rs:6:5: 6:41 note: in this expansion of try! (defined in <std macros>)
<std macros>:5:8: 6:42 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
<std macros>:5:8: 6:42 error: mismatched types:
 expected `()`,
    found `core::result::Result<_, _>`
(expected (),
    found enum `core::result::Result`) [E0308]
<std macros>:5 return $ crate:: result:: Result:: Err (
<std macros>:6 $ crate:: convert:: From:: from ( err ) ) } } )
main.rs:8:17: 8:44 note: in this expansion of try! (defined in <std macros>)
<std macros>:5:8: 6:42 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
<std macros>:5:8: 6:42 error: mismatched types:
 expected `()`,
    found `core::result::Result<_, _>`
(expected (),
    found enum `core::result::Result`) [E0308]
<std macros>:5 return $ crate:: result:: Result:: Err (
<std macros>:6 $ crate:: convert:: From:: from ( err ) ) } } )
main.rs:10:5: 10:36 note: in this expansion of try! (defined in <std macros>)
<std macros>:5:8: 6:42 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
error: aborting due to 4 previous errors
```

It looks to me like it **really** doesn't like those `try!` statements. I am using Rust 1.5.0.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was just to `unwrap` instead of use `try`. `try` is used to bubble up results (which makes sense!)